# Duplicate c# elements, how to simplify the code?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task

There is such a code, how can it be simplified?
I have a problem with canceling task in c#, task[0] does not stop executing. Here is the code.

```
cts1 = new CancellationTokenSource();
cts2 = new CancellationTokenSource();
cts3 = new CancellationTokenSource();
cts4 = new CancellationTokenSource();
cts5 = new CancellationTokenSource();
cts6 = new CancellationTokenSource();
cts7 = new CancellationTokenSource();
cts8 = new CancellationTokenSource();

Task _cockroach1 = SetSpeed(cockroach1, 1);
Task _cockroach2 = SetSpeed(cockroach2, 2);
Task _cockroach3 = SetSpeed(cockroach3, 3);
Task _cockroach4 = SetSpeed(cockroach4, 4);
Task _cockroach5 = SetSpeed(cockroach5, 5);
Task _cockroach6 = SetSpeed(cockroach6, 6);
Task _cockroach7 = SetSpeed(cockroach7, 7);
Task _cockroach8 = SetSpeed(cockroach8, 8);

private async Task SetSpeed(Image _cockroach, int _number)
{
    while (_x <= 830)
    {
        if (_number == 1 && cts1.Token.IsCancellationRequested) return; //остановка таска
        if (_number == 2 && cts2.Token.IsCancellationRequested) return; 
        if (_number == 3 && cts3.Token.IsCancellationRequested) return; 
        if (_number == 4 && cts4.Token.IsCancellationRequested) return; 
        if (_number == 5 && cts5.Token.IsCancellationRequested) return; 
        if (_number == 6 && cts6.Token.IsCancellationRequested) return; 
        if (_number == 7 && cts7.Token.IsCancellationRequested) return; 
        if (_number == 8 && cts8.Token.IsCancellationRequested) return;
```

It's not very clear how to stop tasks.

Comment: Use arrays/collections?

Comment: Usually you would pass the Cancellation token to the method, like `SetSpeed(cockroach1, 1, cts1.Token);` and in the method check only for the token passed as parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of having 9 variables, why not just store all the elements into an array or a list?

```
var cts = Enumerable.Range(0, 9).Select(x => new CancellationTokenSource()).ToArray();
var cockroach = Enumerable.Range(0, 9).Select(x => new CockRoach(...)).ToArray();   
var _cockroaches = cts.Select((x, i) => SetSpeed(cockroach[i], i);

private async Task SetSpeed(Image _cockroach, int _number)
{
    while (_x <= 830)
    {
        if (cts[number].Token.IsCancellationRequested) return;
    }
    // ...
}
```

When you don't like LINQ-syntax, you can also use good old-styled loops:

```
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource[9];
var cockroaches = new Image[9];
var _cockroaches = new Task[9];

for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
{
    cts[i] = new CancellationTokenSource();
    cockroaches[i] = new Image(...);
    _cockroaches [i] = SetSpeed(cockroaches[i], i);
}
```